# Cloudant geo search query with timestamp sorting

Tags: cloudant

I have a database of geospatial documents (type: 'Feature' & geometry:...) with a 'date' field as a timestamp (created time).
What is the best way sort the documents by 'date' timestamp?

Looking at the docs - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant-geo.html#querying-a-cloudant-geo-index, there is no 'sort' parameter to the .geo() query object. Is the 'in memory' the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There's no way to sort when using the geo index. If you want to do that, you can [use Lucene geo as described in this blog post](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/01/07/geospatial-query-with-cloudant-search/), but the spatial part will be limited to bounding box queries.